# Display Icon on form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, imagelist

How would I display an Icon at 48x48 resolution on a form in vb.net?
I looked at using imagelist , but I don't know how to display the image that I add to the list using code and how to specify it's coordinates on the form.
I did some google searching but none of the examples really show what I need to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ImageList is not ideal when you have image formats supporting alpha transparency (at least it this used to be the case; I didn't use them a lot recently), so you are probably better off loading the icon from a file on disk or from a resource. If you load it from disk you can use this approach:

```
' Function for loading the icon from disk in 48x48 size '
Private Function LoadIconFromFile(ByVal fileName As String) As Icon
    Return New Icon(fileName, New Size(48, 48))
End Function

' code for loading the icon into a PictureBox '
Dim theIcon As Icon = LoadIconFromFile("C:\path\file.ico")
pbIcon.Image = theIcon.ToBitmap()
theIcon.Dispose()

' code for drawing the icon on the form, at x=20, y=20 '
Dim g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
Dim theIcon As Icon = LoadIconFromFile("C:\path\file.ico")
g.DrawIcon(theIcon, 20, 20)
g.Dispose()
theIcon.Dispose()
```

Update: if you instead want to have the icon as an embedded resource in your assembly, you can alter the LoadIconFromFile method so that it looks like this instead:

```
Private Function LoadIconFromFile(ByVal fileName As String) As Icon
    Dim result As Icon
    Dim assembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = Me.GetType().Assembly
    Dim stream As System.IO.Stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream((assembly.GetName().Name & ".file.ico"))
    result = New Icon(stream, New Size(48, 48))
    stream.Dispose()
    Return result
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a picturebox control to place the image on the form.

You can then set the Image property to the image you wish to display, be that from a file on disk, an image list or a resource file.

Assuming you have a picturebox called pct:

```
pct.Image = Image.FromFile("c:\Image_Name.jpg")  'file on disk
```

or

```
pct.Image = My.Resources.Image_Name 'project resources
```

or

```
pct.Image = imagelist.image(0)  'imagelist
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Me.Icon = Icon.FromHandle(DirectCast(ImgLs_ICONS.Images(0), Bitmap).GetHicon())
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please elaborate your answer

Comment: This is really unhelpful. One line with nothing explained and the code gives off syntax errors in Visual Basic. Are we supposed to read your mind to make use of this answer? (-1)

Comment: This works perfectly.   I just changed the ...Images(0), to My.Resources.mypngfile, and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a label control to do the same thing. I used one to draw a dot over an image in a picturebox control. It might be less overhead than using a PictureBox.

```
        Dim label As Label = New Label()
        label.Size = My.Resources.DefectDot.Size
        label.Image = My.Resources.DefectDot ' Already an image so don't need ToBitmap 
        label.Location = New Point(40, 40)
        DefectPictureBox.Controls.Add(label)
```

Using the OnPaint method might be the best way of doing this.

```
Private Sub DefectPictureBox_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles DefectPictureBox.Paint
    e.Graphics.DrawIcon(My.Resources.MyDot, 20, 20)
End Sub
```